# Google Ecommerce Data - Items not attached to Transaction

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I am getting data sent to the ecommerce view on my analytics dashboard - but the items aren't being attached to the transaction - it looks like the items are coming through as transactions as well.

Am I mistaken or should the items be attached to the transaction? What am I dong wrong here.

```
// Build e-commerce items for each item groups
            let items = _.map(basket.item_groups, (group) => {
                let category = group.type && 'events' || 'products';
                let id = group.type && `tt-${group.type}` || `pa-${group.product_attribute}`;
                return {
                    'id': id,
                    'name': group.description,
                    'sku': id,
                    'category': category,  // causes problems if removed entirely
                    'price': group.price,
                    'quantity': group.quantity,
                    'currency': basket.currency,
                };
            });

            let transaction = {
                'id': basket.id,  // Transaction ID. Required.
                'affiliation': basket.payment_venue,  // Affiliation or store name.
                'revenue': basket.total_price,
                'shipping': 0,
                'tax': basket.taxes,
            };

            this.call(`${this.namespace}.ecommerce:addTransaction`, transaction);

            _.each(items, (item) => {
                this.call(`${this.namespace}.ecommerce:addItem`, item);
            });

            this.call(`${this.namespace}.ecommerce:send`);
```

[image: pa- and tt- are items]

[image: Transaction detail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `id` property for your items isn't set to the transaction ID, which it needs to be. Instead you're giving each product its own SKU/ID in *both* the `id` and `sku` fields.

When defining the item, it looks like you just need:

```
'id': basket.id,
```

In the classic ecommerce tracking, the items and transactions are sent as individual hits (unlike Enhanced Ecommerce), so every item needs to be linked to the transaction. You're instead assigning your products to transactions with the SKU instead of the transaction ID, which is why they show up as transactions without revenue.